# Legend ggplot using geom_vline

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I know there are similar questions that have been asked, but none have so far succeeded in getting my legend to show. I have used (1) show.legend = True (2) Mapping xintercept and colour in aes inside geom_vline and then adding scale_colour_manual.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(post_reg,aes(x=B_0)) + geom_density() + xlab(expression(beta[0]))+ 
  ylab("Density \n")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(1,average_values[2],quantiles[1,2],quantiles[3,2]),color=c("green","blue","red","red"),
                                linetype = c("solid","solid","dashed","dashed"))
```

Which produces the following image:

[image: PLOT]

How else can I add a legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way when you have multiple lines is to make a separate dataframe containing a column for the x intercepts and a column for whatever you want those lines to be named in the legend, then apply the mapping in `ggplot` to that data frame.  Here's a representative example:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10000, 10, 1))
lines <- data.frame(
  intercepts = c(1,16,7,13,9,11),
  names = c('Lines 1', 'Lines 1', 'Lines 2', 'Lines 2', 'Lines 3', 'Lines 3')
)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + geom_density() + xlim(0,20) + theme_bw() +
  geom_vline(
    data=lines,
    aes(xintercept = intercepts, color=names, linetype=names),
    size=1, key_glyph='path'
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('Lines 1' = 'blue', 'Lines 2' = 'green', 'Lines 3' = 'red')) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('Lines 1' = 'dotted', 'Lines 2' = 'dashed', "Lines 3" = "solid"))
```

[image]

Herein, the `geom_vline()` call assigns the data to the `lines` dataset, and then I specify the mapping of `lines$intercepts` and `lines$names` within `aes()`.  This creates the legend and the associated legend key names.  By default, the key glyphs (the icons in the legend) shown for `geom_vline` are vertical lines, so I changed them here by specifying `key_glyph="path"` to match that typically seen in, for example, `geom_line()`.

This will work as is, but in order to specify a particular color or linetype style, you can specify the colors and linetypes to be used using `scale_*_manual()` functions and supplying a named vector for each of the `values=` arguments.

Comment: This is great thank you! What if I have multiple plots with different intercepts ? Would I have to create a seperate dataframe for each plot?

Comment: It depends.  If you have a faceted plot, you just need to ensure there is a column in your "vertical line" dataset that corresponds to the facets (same name of column and same labels as your data), and it will map correctly on each plot.  If you have a completely separate plot, you can have a different dataframe through subsetting or filtering another way.  Instead of `data = lines` you might use `data = subset(lines, plot_num == 1)` or something like that.  This is why I say, it depends.